# concatenate lines in Python if next line not matches pattern

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Hi I have encore captions file that looks like this:

```
00:00:29:02 00:00:35:00 text 1
text 2
00:00:36:04 00:00:44:08 text 3
text 4
00:00:44:12 00:00:48:00 text 5
00:00:49:17 00:00:52:17 text 6
```

in python what should I put instead of "HELP PLEASE"

```
newdata = re.sub("""HELP PLEASE""", r"\1", filedata)
```

to produce the lines like this:

```
00:00:29:02 00:00:35:00 text 1 text 2
00:00:36:04 00:00:44:08 text 3 text 4
00:00:44:12 00:00:48:00 text 5
00:00:49:17 00:00:52:17 text 6
```

thank you

Comment: Why are people obsessed with regexes? Just process the file line by line.

Comment: If the texts are not that long, I think you still can use a regex here, there is nothing wrong with using regex whenever it suits a specific purpose. Use [`\n(?!\d{2}(?::\d{2})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nP4oG0/1) to replace with a space (no backreferences). Or [`\n(\D)` to replace with r" \1"](https://regex101.com/r/nP4oG0/2). Only if you understand what you are doing :).

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: This can be done without a regex line by line, all you have to do is keep checking the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file isn't too big, you can read each line into a new list. If a line doesn't start with the timestamp, then pop the last line added to `new_lines` and add it back with the new line appended to it.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> # assume all_lines = somefile.readlines() or use it in the for loop below.
... # but simplying to this
... all_lines = [
... "00:00:29:02 00:00:35:00 text 1",
... "text 2",
... "00:00:36:04 00:00:44:08 text 3",
... "text 4",
... "00:00:44:12 00:00:48:00 text 5",
... "00:00:49:17 00:00:52:17 text 6",
... "text 7",  # added for interest
... "text 8",  # added for interest
... ]
>>>
>>> new_lines = []
>>> for line in all_lines:
...     if not re.match('(?:(?:\d\d:){3}(?:\d\d) ){2}.*', line):
...         # line did not start with a timestamp
...         new_lines.append(new_lines.pop() + ' ' + line)
...     else:
...         new_lines.append(line)
...
>>> print '\n'.join(new_lines)
00:00:29:02 00:00:35:00 text 1 text 2
00:00:36:04 00:00:44:08 text 3 text 4
00:00:44:12 00:00:48:00 text 5
00:00:49:17 00:00:52:17 text 6 text 7 text 8
>>>
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to use a `prev_line` variable which you keep dumping/yielding instead of a potentially massive `new_lines`.

Btw, this will fail if the first line is not a timestamp.

PS: Don't know why everyone's being so -ve about regex's.

---

Edit: Without creating a potentially massive new_lines list...

```
>>> prev_line = ''
>>> for line in all_lines:
...     if not re.match('(?:(?:\d\d:){3}(?:\d\d) ){2}.*', line):
...         prev_line += ' ' + line
...     else:
...         if prev_line:  # prevents the first flag '' prev_line from printing
...             print prev_line
...         prev_line = line
...
00:00:29:02 00:00:35:00 text 1 text 2
00:00:36:04 00:00:44:08 text 3 text 4
00:00:44:12 00:00:48:00 text 5
>>> print prev_line  # make sure to print/dump the last one
00:00:49:17 00:00:52:17 text 6 text 7 text 8
>>>
```

Two caveats: (1.) If a line is actually blank, it will get skipped. (2.) While the second version with `prev_line` is memory efficient even if the file is massive, it will take up memory if you have *many* consecutive lines without a timestamp (like line 7 and 8) - `prev_line` has to hold all of it until there's a line with a timestamp. You could work around it by dumping to a file, without explicit newlines (`\n`) and adding a newline before dumping a line which *does* start with a timestamp.

Comment: For the record, @stribizhev's comment is a convenient re.sub. And more to the point of the question - user asking for a the right regex to use.